# Launch application on guest where there is a host app of the same name

Tags: macos, applescript, parallels

I am running Parallels for desktop 9 on a Mac with Mavericks, with a Windows 8.1 guest OS. I'm using shared guest applications.

I can launch most apps on the guest just by calling `activate` on them, like this

`tell application "Sticky Notes" to activate` - this works fine

But when it comes to Microsoft Office applications, where I have native Office 2011 on the Mac and also Office 2013 on the guest, I can't work out how to launch the Windows version of the app. This occurs when there is an application of the same name on the host and guest.

`tell application "Outlook" to activate` opens Outlook on the Mac

`tell application "Macintosh HD:Users:me:Applications (Parallels):Windows 8 Applications:Microsoft Outlook.app" to activate` causes AppleScript, when attempting to run the script, to return an error saying it can't be found.

I've tried several similar combinations but they all either return this same error, or prompt me to browse to an application but the browse window is scoped to the native Mac Applications folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here's how I've worked out to do it - not quite satisfactory, but it will do for me:

`tell application "/Users/me/Applications (Parallels)/{<some-guid>} Applications.localized/Microsoft Outlook.app" to activate`

where the above path (including `<some-guid>`) comes from manually launching the app, then right-clicking it in the dock > Options > Show In Finder. Obviously not a solution that will generalise to other users/other machines.

I'd still like to know how to get the application id and/or bundle identifier for a Parallels application, so I could use that as the argument instead of the posix path.